# Derivative of an Integral with function on the bounds

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I want to calculate the following derivative: $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^{s(t)}u(x,t)dx=\frac{d}{dt}F(t)$$

My idea was calculating the limit:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h}$$
which is:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_a^{s(t+h)}u(x,t+h)dx-\int_a^{s(t)}u(x,t)dx}{h}$$
I tried to add and remove $u(x,t)$ in the first integral.
and it gives:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_a^{s(t+h)}u(x,t+h)-u(x,t)dx+\int_{s(t)}^{s(t+h)}u(x,t)dx}{h}$$
can we say that this equals to: $\int_a^{s(t)}u_t(x,t)dx+s'(t).u(s(t),t)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

By Newton–Leibniz
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^{s(t)}u(x,t)dx=s'(t)\, u(s(t),t)+\int_a^{s(t)}\frac{\partial u(x,t)} {\partial t }  \, dx$$ which is what you wrote.

For the more general case
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{s(t)}u(x,t)dx=s'(t)\,u(s(t),t)-a'(t)\, u(a(t),t)+\int_{a(t)}^{s(t)} \frac{\partial u(x,t)} {\partial t } \, dx$$ and tou see what happens if $\frac{\partial u(x,t)} {\partial t }=0$.

Comment: Where does the integral term come from on the RHS?

Comment: @Axion004. Just because $u(x,t)$ and not $u(x)$.